# Will ByteBuffer.wrap(byte[]) cause memory leak for long-running applications?

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I tried to search online, but did not find answers.

Based on the [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#wrap(byte[])), ByteBuffer.wrap() create a new ByteBuffer in each call. In a long-running application, if the gc is not triggered, but the app has been continuously calling ByteBuffer.wrap(), the application may use a lot more memory out side of the java heap, and cause potential memory leak. Is is right?

```
public static ByteBuffer wrap(byte[] array)

Wraps a byte array into a buffer.

The new buffer will be backed by the given byte array; that is, modifications 
to the buffer will cause the array to be modified and vice versa. The new 
buffer's capacity and limit will be array.length, its position will be zero,    
and its mark will be undefined. Its backing array will be the given array, and
its array offset will be zero.
```

Based on the jdk code, it seems that the answer is no, as ByteBuffer.wrap() creates a new HeapByteBuffer object, but did not allocate a new buffer underneath.

```
public static ByteBuffer wrap(byte[] array,
                                int offset, int length)
{
    try {
        return new HeapByteBuffer(array, offset, length);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException x) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, can you post your source code?

Comment: I don't understand your concern. If a number of references you create permanently grows then of course you will run out of memory. Otherwise if references are discarded at some point then there will be no memory leak.

Comment: I've also experienced this issue when using ByteBuffer for sending websockets messages. The problem is that even if the references are discarded, eventually the memory becomes full. @yuyang: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @AndreiF I haven't found the solution yet. I put a workaround to restart the process daily to reduce the side effect of memory leakage.

Answer (score 3):

It's only an issue if you are keeping hard references of the arrays or the wrapping ByteBuffers.

The "wrap" method does not allocate memory out side of the heap like a direct ByteBuffer.  The garbage collector should be able to clean it up before an OutOfMemory error occurs.