# Jetty - Possible memory leak when using websockets and ByteBuffer

Tags: java, memory-leaks, websocket, jetty, bytebuffer

I'm using Jetty 9.3.5.v20151012 to deliver a large number of events to clients using websockets. The events consist of 3 parts: a number, an event type and a timestamp and each event is serialized as byte[] and sent  using ByteBuffer.

After a certain number of hours/days, depending on the number of clients, I notice an increase in heap memory and without any possibility for the GC to recover it. 
When the heap (set to 512MB) is almost full, the memory used by the jvm is about 700-800 MB and the CPU is at 100% (it seams like the GC is trying very often to clean up). At the beginning, when I start Jetty, the memory is at about 30MB when calling the GC but after some time, this number increases more and more. Eventually the process is killed.

I'm using jvisualvm as profiler for memory leak debug and I've attached some screenshots of the head dump:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is the main code that handles the message sending using ByteBuffer:

I basically have a method that creates a byte[] (fullbytes) for all events that need to be sent in one message:

```
byte[] numberBytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putFloat(number).array();
byte[] eventBytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(2).putShort(event).array();
byte[] timestampBytes  = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putDouble(timestamp).array();

for (int i = 0; i < eventBytes.length; i++) {
    fullbytes[i + scount*eventLength] = eventBytes[i];
}

for (int i = 0; i < numberBytes.length; i++) {
    fullbytes[eventBytes.length + i + scount*eventLength] = numberBytes[i];
}

for (int i = 0; i < timestampBytes.length; i++) {
    fullbytes[numberBytes.length + eventBytes.length + i + scount*eventLength] = timestampBytes[i];
}
```

And then another method (called in a separate thread) that sends the bytes on the websockets

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(fullbytes);
wsSession.getRemote().sendBytesByFuture(bb);
bb.clear();
```

As I've read on a few place (in documentation or [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Prevent_Memory_Leaks#Direct_ByteBuffers) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32235309/will-bytebuffer-wrapbyte-cause-memory-leak-for-long-running-applications)), this issue should not appear, since I'm not using direct ByteBuffer. Could this be a bug related to Jetty / websockets?

Please advise!

**EDIT:**

I've made some more tests and I have noticed that the problem appears when sending messages to a client that is not connected, but jetty has not received the onClose event (for ex. a user puts his laptop in standby). Because the on close event is not triggered, the server code doesn't unregister the client and keeps trying to send the messages to that client. I don't know why but the close event is received after 1 or 2 hours. Also, sometimes (in don't know the context yet) although the event is received and the client (socket) is unregistered, a reference to a WebSocketSession object (for that client) still hangs. I haven't found out why this happens yet.

Until then, I have 2 possible workarounds, but I have no idea how to achieve them (that have other good uses as well):

1. Always detect when a connection is not open (or closed temporarily, for ex. user puts laptop in standby). I tried using sendPing() and implementing onFrame() but I couldn't find a solution. Is there a way to do this?
2. Periodically "flush" the buffer. How can I discard the messages that were not sent to the client so they don't keep on queuing?

**EDIT 2**

This may be pointing the topic to another direction so I made another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34872692/jetty-websockets-correctly-sending-async-messages-when-handling-unreliable-con).

**EDIT 3**

I've done some more tests regarding the large number of messages/bytes sent and I found out why "it seamed" that the memory leak only appeared sometimes: when sending bytes async on a different thread than the one used when sevlet.configure() is called, after a large build-up, the memory is not being released after the client disconnects. Also I couldn't simulate the memory leak when using sendBytes(ByteBuffer), only with sendBytesByFuture(ByteBuffer) and sendBytes(ByteBuffer, WriteCallback).

This seams very strangem but I don't believe I'm doing something "wrong" in the tests.

Code:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory) {
    factory.getPolicy().setIdleTimeout(1000 * 0);
    factory.setCreator(new WebSocketCreator() {

    @Override
    public Object createWebSocket(ServletUpgradeRequest req,
            ServletUpgradeResponse resp) {
        return new WSTestMemHandler();
    }
}); 
}

@WebSocket
public class WSTestMemHandler {
    private boolean connected = false;
    private int n = 0;

    public WSTestMemHandler(){
    }

    @OnWebSocketClose
    public void onClose(int statusCode, String reason) {
        connected = false;
        connections --;
        //print debug
    }

    @OnWebSocketError
    public void onError(Throwable t) {
    //print debug
    }

    @OnWebSocketConnect
    public void onConnect(final Session session) throws InterruptedException {

        connected = true;
        connections ++;
    //print debug

        //the code running in another thread will trigger memory leak 
        //when to client endpoint is down and messages are still sent 
        //because the GC will not cleanup after onclose received and
        //client disconnects

        //if the "while" loop is run in the same thread, the memory 
        //can be released when onclose is received, but that would
        //mean to hold the onConnect() method and not return. I think
        //this would be bad practice.

        new Thread(new Runnable() { 

            @Override
            public void run() {

                while (connected) {

                    testBytesSend(session);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(4);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }

                }
                //print debug
            }
        }).start();


    }



    private void testBytesSend(Session session) {

        try {
            int noEntries = 200;
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(noEntries * 14);
            for (int i = 0; i < noEntries; i++) {
                n+= 1.0f;
                bb.putFloat(n);
                bb.putShort((short)1);
                bb.putDouble(123456789123.0);
            }
            bb.flip();


            session.getRemote().sendBytes(bb, new WriteCallback() {

                @Override
                public void writeSuccess() {

                }

                @Override
                public void writeFailed(Throwable arg0) {

                }
            });


        //print debug
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: How do you determine that "without any possibility for the GC to recover it"? Do you get an OutOfMemoryError?

Comment: Hi, I've edited my post.

Comment: When the heap (set to 512MB) is almost full, the memory used by the jvm is about 700-800 MB and the CPU is at 100% (it seams like the GC is trying very often to clean up). At the beginning, when I start Jetty, the memory is at about 30MB when calling the GC but after some time, this number increases more and more. Eventually the process is killed.
I don't wait till it runs completely out of memory, because the CPU is at 100% and the server becomes unusable; And I can't seam to reproduce the issue in development.

Comment: Hi Andrei, I am running into the same OOM issue while using async sendString using jetty 9.4 websockets. Was this issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Your `ByteBuffer` use is incredibly inefficient.

Don't create all of those minor/tiny ByteBuffers just to get a byte array, and then toss it out. ick.

> *Note:* you don't even use the `.array()` call correctly, as not all `ByteBuffer` allocations have a backing array you can access like that.

The byte array's `numberBytes`, `eventBytes`, `timestampBytes`, and `fullbytes` should not exist.

Create a single `ByteBuffer`, representing the entire message you intend to send, allocate it it to be either the size you need, or larger.

Then put the individual bytes you want into it, flip it, and give the Jetty implementation that single `ByteBuffer`.

Jetty will use the standard `ByteBuffer` information (such as `position` and `limit`) to determine what part of that `ByteBuffer` should actually be sent.

Comment: So if i understand correctly, to prevent the memory leak: I should use the methods putFloat, putShort, putDouble (instead of creating arrays for each event info and using wrap method) and call them on the same ByteBuffer object; then use flip() to mark it for reading and then sending it thorough the websockets? And also, should I use the same ByteBuffer for all messages sent and not creating new ByteBuffer objects for each of them? (or for this last one there is no difference?)

Comment: As for the last question in your comment, once you hand the ByteBuffer to Jetty its no longer yours, don't reuse it.

Comment: Hi again, I haven't found the cause of the memory leak, but it seams that some code is keeping jetty from freeing session related objects. It might be something from the way i'm using factory.setCreator() in webSocketServlet.configure() but I'm still working on this... In the meantime I'm trying to find other solutions/workarounds.

Comment: Please try Jetty `9.3.7.v20160115`, it contains a speculative fix for [bug #481986](https://bugs.eclipse.org/481986)

Comment: Ok, I'll try 9.3.7. In the meantime, I've also added another post with questions regarding the proper way to handle websocket connections here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34872692/jetty-websockets-correctly-sending-async-messages-when-handling-unreliable-con

Comment: Hi Joakim, I didn't manage to install the new version yet, but I couldn't find out why the mem leak issue  appeared only sometimes so  I've made some more tests and edited my post.